# Owl carousel not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have done nothing with jquery and very little with JavaScript, and am trying to add an Owl Carousel with a few images to my page. I've pasted code from their site, which in theory should work, the variable names seem to add up, but it doesn't display on my page at all. Sorry, this is all new to me and I can't seem to find any answers anywhere else.

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="EvositeCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<script src="EvositeJS.js"> </script>
</head>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

<div class="item"> <img src="Images/EvositeLogo.PNG"> </div> 
<div class="item"> <img src="Images/DiabetesUKLogo.PNG"> </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#owl-demo .item{
margin: 3px;
}

#owl-demo .item img{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

  items : 4,
  itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
  itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

 });

 });
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function(anonymous function) @ EvositeJS.js:5m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503

Comment: I think you are missing a reference to the owl.carousel.js ... reading the documentation, you need to add something like this <script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

Comment: Oh right! Found the file! The images have appeared now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reference the `owl.carousel.js` file as follows:

```
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Though the images appear now, it's meant to be a carousel, that doesn't appear at all, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to adding js file , your css file path may not be correct

if you have added the script using the following path

```
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

then the css path should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
```

also for responsive screen item limitation use

```
    responsive : {
        480 : { items : 4  },
        768 : { items : 6  },
        1024 : { items : 8
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery version 1.11.3 not support with Carousel 1.3.3 you must downgrade to jquery 1.8x or Update Owlcarousel to Latest available version